# Should the Domain ever access Application Services of another system?

Tags: architecture, service, domain-driven-design, distributed-system

Spefically across two systems: can the domain of system A call the application services/remote facade of system B?

For example if an Ordering System has an Order entity in its domain, should the validation method of that Order entity call an applicaion service of a Stock Keeping Service to check there is enough product in stock to fulfil the order?

My instinct is that this is not the correct way of doing things.

This is a simplified version of a previous, rather convoluted question: 
[Integration between various Domain Driven Design systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523282/integration-between-various-domain-driven-design-systems)
It is not nessacery or advised that you refer to this previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would pay to consider your architecture. Why is it necessary that your domain logic hooks into another domain directly? Can it not consume data that the other domain publishes? If not, are we really talking about two disjoint domains, or are they really part of the same bounded context?

It may be that the other system is a closed one, so that you cannot extend it. It may also be that that other system does not publish its data based on events, and that you can only access it through an API. In that case, it would be best to use an agent in your domain model. That is, your domain logic should contain an agent (proxy) that connects to the remote system but acts like it's local. This encapsulates even the fact that the actual logic/data is not local.

Comment: I have provided a trivial example, but what if system B is doing some complex derived calculation based on the data that you would not want to replicate in system A? Perhaps system B should perform the calculation at persistence time, save the data as a derived field and then publish that derived data? Regarding your second paragraph: do you mean like a segregated interface that could be injected in? ICheckStockLevelChecker for example?

Comment: Exactly, that's the best way to go. System B is responsible for its own data according to its own model, and so is System A. If you can keep both systems independent of each other, but consuming each other's events, that would be a maintainable and stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are many ways to overcome such a problem.
First of all, why does your domain model need to have access to the others domain models?

a)For making more complicated domain model ==> This domain model can be user in Service layer for making ViewModel. ==> This viewModel will be return to the client.

In this case, assembling should take part in your service layer, not in Domain layer. In other words, send some request to your domain model and adjacent services, get the result from them, compose them together in a particular ViewModel, and finally return the result to the client.

b)Your domain model is responsible for checking some business rules. Suppose that some of them will be checked in other systems and so you made a decision for having access to adjacent systems in your domain model.

Considering that the responsibility of your domain model - belong to your system - is exactly checking some rules about your system, not anythings outside its boundary. I mean, your domain model should not have access to other systems domains. It makes some dependency between these systems. It is not good approach based on service oriented architecture. This is against loosely-coupled design. Instead you should orchestrate between these systems in your service layer. service layer sends some request to different systems and get some response from them. Now the final decision will be make according to the overall result.